# R: How to convert a number with "E" to a float number?

Tags: r

I have a matrix with the Ordinal Logit-model results. Unfortunately, there are no suitable packages that could provide a normal regression output for the ordinal logit case. So, I compute p-values literally with my own hands in R.

Matrix looks like this:

```
structure(c(0.0669861986346363, -0.114232676171834, -0.107373851689376, 
-0.176084578750548, 0.112188588953131, 0.0931008248106333, 0.118059668574154, 
0.0966677417716179, 0.597085668513231, -1.22697813262323, -0.909487998621093, 
-1.82154434895724, 0.550450185753641, 0.219830809958716, 0.363092589967286, 
0.0685241516219639), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("interpersonal_trust", 
"depersonificated_trust", "trust_ingroup", "trust_outgroup"), 
    c("Value", "Std. Error", "t value", "p value")))
```

In the `dput` output everything is okay though, in my RStudio environment numbers look like this:

```
                           Value     Std. Error   t value     p value
interpersonal_trust     0.06698620   0.11218859   0.5970857  5.504502e-01
depersonificated_trust -0.11423268   0.09310082  -1.2269781  2.198308e-01
trust_ingroup          -0.10737385   0.11805967  -0.9094880  3.630926e-01
trust_outgroup         -0.17608458   0.09666774  -1.8215443  6.852415e-02
```

What are the possible ways to convert p-value values into a float numbers, without `e`? Is there any function in R to perform it? Float type would definitely simplify the process of considering variables' statistical significance.

Comment: Try `options(scipen = 999)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that one was very fast and thanks to @akrun.

Writing `options(scipen = 999)` into the RStudio console gave me the desirable solution.

Moreover, this "problem" could be overcome by rounding the value of the p-value:

```
p <- round(pnorm(abs(ctable[,"t value"]), lower.tail = F) * 2, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I used this fast formatting code for check the result:

```
dput <- format(dput$p,scientific = FALSE)
```

I hope this will work for you, as well.